# How to make Fiddler decrypt HTTPS sites when it is inside an application created by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, fiddler

I've been using Fiddler in my C# app to get webtrends tags. I've also included a builtin webbrowser to automatically read and open a list of URLs one by one. after a server response has been received, the browser goes to the next list. But there are just pages that are in HTTPS and the embedded Fiddler can't access those because the following message appears:

"There is a problem with this website's security certificate."

i'm not sure if it's the Fiddler that is limited to searching only for non HTTPS sites, or the webbrowser control that is not capable of accessing those.

Any code that can help with my present situation, or any thoughts why i can't view https sites with the current tandem that i have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're using FiddlerCore? Did you call the method to trust the Fiddler self-signed root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have configured Fiddler to capture AND decrypt HTTPS sessions. Further check your personal certificate store, can you find a DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot certificate there?

Comment: Hi dominik! just revisited this question of mine after sometime. Never did i know that the Fiddler itself and the app i made that contains fiddler dlls are related. even with IE itself! Just followed your instructions and I guess i went to the right path and solved my problem. Thanks! Also, i noticed that when i enter a site in IE that requires credentials to be browsed, enter the username and password, then save that credentials, it will automatically apply to FiddlerCore, thus enabling my app to scan that site for traffic using FiddlerCore without any hassle.